# Understanding the AngularFire extend FirebaseArray example?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I've been struggling with the proper implementation of this, I thought I had it but based on the example I am doing it wrong. How do you use this factory in a controller? What is the intended result?

The example:

```
app.factory("ListWithTotal", ["$FirebaseArray", "$firebase", function($FirebaseArray, $firebase) {
  // create a new factory based on $FirebaseArray
  var TotalFactory = $FirebaseArray.$extendFactory({
    getTotal: function() {
      var total = 0;
      // the array data is located in this.$list
      angular.forEach(this.$list, function(rec) {
        total += rec.amount;
      });
      return total;
    }
  });
  return function(listRef) {
    // override the factory used by $firebase
    **// why do listRef and ref not match here?
    //where does listRef or ref come from**
    var sync = $firebase(ref, {arrayFactory: TotalFactory});
    return sync.$asArray(); // this will be an instance of TotalFactory
  }
}]);
```

I've been able to use a version of extending factories that doesn't include the return of a reference to a new firebase. For example: A todo list that keeps count: http://plnkr.co/edit/iAGvPHFWn2GSPGzBRpKh?p=preview

Comment: It's a typo. They should both be `listRef`, or `ref`. Not one and the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a typo. They should both be `listRef`, or `ref`. Not one and the other.

As the ListWithTotal factory returns a function, you use it in the controller like this:

```
.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $window, ListWithTotal) {
    var ref = new $window.Firebase("//some-url/data");
    $scope.listWithTotal = ListWithTotal(ref);
});
```

Comment: Cool, so it replaces the $firebase function. Is the $window necessary there? I usually just write var ref = new Firebase('/path-to-firebase');

Comment: As `$window` is Angular's wrapper around the window object, any properties of the global object (like `Firebase`) are also available on `$window`. Having your code reference `$window` makes it easy for you to mock things from the global scope in your tests.